# .htaccess redirect to another domain except admin page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal

I am asking because I can not for the live of me figure out what is wrong and so far none of the StackOverflow answers worked.

I have to redirect a domain to another subdomain, except the admin. For example:

sub1.domain.com/testsite/ shoud redirect to "sub2.domain.com/testsite/",
but sub1.domain.com/admin/ or "sub1.domain.com/de/admin/" should stay right where it is.

As a first step I tried to only check for the "admin", so everything would be redirected except "sub1.domain.com/admin/":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/admin
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http\:\/\/sub2\.domain\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This one looked most promising, but it is not working. The second condition is not working and the admin page still gets redirected.

If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

---

EDIT:
I should have said that its a multi-domain site, which means we have a .htaccess file for all sites and that is the reason I specifically check for the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

I just found the reason (besides my stupidity). The site I should redirect was a Drupal Site. Thats why all links end up at the same location:

sub1.domain.com/index.php

The reason why my above Rewrite Condition was not working is, that sub1.domain.com/admin is being redirected to sub1.domain.com/index.php, which consequently ends up at: "sub2.domain.com/index.php". The correct rewrite rule looks like that:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.domain\.com
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|index\.php|de\/admin|it\/admin|user|de\/user|it\/user)
 RewriteRule (.*) http://sub2.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This redirects everything except:

```
sub1.domain.com/admin
sub1.domain.com/de/admin
sub1.domain.com/it/admin
sub1.domain.com/user
sub1.domain.com/de/user
sub1.domain.com/it/user
```

and of course

```
sub1.domain.com/index.php
```

Since the last one also should not be redirected if the user types it in directly, it is not a perfect solution, but I can live with it.

Comment: If I want to only allow /index.php/?route=api/login url then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting this, but I can't test it! 
But I guess this redirects EVERYTHING except that one domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub1.domain.com/admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$http\:\/\/sub2\.domain\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond is use to check condition weather to execute .htacess or not

For your case the solution may be as below:-

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(admin)$ http://sub1.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub2.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```